# coffeescript and enum values

Tags: enums, coffeescript

I was playing around with the concept of enums / constants in coffeescript ( http://coffeescript.org/ ) and came up with the following code below which seems OK. How can I enhance this to be even better for something where an enum would fit? google searches for this have not yet revealed satisfaction.

```
class SomeService

  @SomeEnumValue : 400
  @SomeOtherValue : 402

  someFunc: ->
    SomeService.SomeEnumValue 

ok = new SomeService()
alert ok.someFunc()

if (ok.someFunc() == SomeService.SomeEnumValue) then alert ' some enum value'
```

Comment: What is it exactly that you're looking for? JavaScript doesn't have constants and its enums are just hashes, so anything you come up in CoffeeScript with will be similarly shaped. For CS enums, I just build up a hash like so: @Colors = Red: 1, Blue: 2

Comment: I wanted to make sure I was not missing something. Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The whole concept of enum is just useless in dynamic languages as is tuple, typed list, map and lots of other stuff, and Javascript (Coffeescript) is dynamic. While working with dynamic language you just have to forget about type checking and use the existing more general constructs to solve your problem. Use arrays instead of lists and tuples, use objects instead of maps and enums and just trust the type of value passed to the function, but heavily unit-test your code. For better or worse (for worse IMO) that's just how a work is done here.

In your case I would recommend just storing your values in a singleton object, like so:

```
HTTPStatusCodes = 
  ok : 200
  badRequest : 400
  unauthorized : 401
```

and accessing it like so:

```
class SomeService
  okCode: ->
    HTTPStatusCodes.ok
  failureCodes: ->
    code for key, code of HTTPStatusCodes when code >= 400
```

Comment: How are tuples and maps useless?

Comment: @Darthfett Don't take my words out of context. I said that they are useless **in dynamic languages**. And that's so because there are no type restrictions in dynamic languages, which, for instance, erases a boundary between tuple and array. In static languages on the other hand constructs like that are just indispensable.

Comment: I love your solution and it's perfect for me. I get your point about emums being useless in dynamic languages in terms of type restriction but in terms of code readability they're absolutely essential. Your solution provides that perfectly.

Comment: Addendum: Python has tuples and it has its uses, since they are immutable you can use them as keys in dictionaries for example.

Comment: I recommend uppercase variable names, since in many languages, including javascript, it usually means 'constant'.

Answer (score 6):

I know I'm late to the party, but for posterity I offer up a "coffeethonic" solution (in the spirit of less-typing):

```
[ a, b, c ] = [1..3]
```

Answer (score 4):

I strongly disagree with the statement that Enums are useless due to the dynamic nature of Javascript or the Enums are more less glorified hashes.

To quote Wikipedia: "A variable that has been declared as having an enumerated type can be assigned any of the enumerators as a value." **And only these enumerators are possible as values.**

Coffeescript can easily and syntactically pleasing emulate an Enum. Including error handling on invalid enumeration values (albeit only at run time)

I have created an example that is mostly functional in nature and uses anonymous callback
functions as a means of assignment - basically substituting the assignment operator "=" for 
Coffeescripts function operator "->". It makes the most syntactically dense code in my book.
However a more class based approach is certainly possible.

```
#define enumeration
httpcodes = Enum 
    ok: 200
    badRequest: 400
    unauthorized: 401
    server_error: 500

#set enum variables with some default state
chrome = httpcodes -> @server_error 
firefox = httpcodes -> @server_error
safari = httpcodes -> @server_error

console.log "httpcodes.ok:" + httpcodes.ok

#change enum value
chrome -> @ok
firefox -> @badRequest
safari -> @unauthorized

console.log "chrome:" + chrome ->
console.log "firefox:" + firefox ->
console.log "safari:" + safari ->

console.log "(chrome ->) == httpcodes.ok:" + ((chrome ->) == httpcodes.ok)

#set an invalid value
try
    safari -> 999
catch err
    console.log err 
    console.log "safari:" + safari ->
```

And here is the code to create an Enum (you need to put this on top of the code
if you want to run it. Just wanted to show the usage code before the implementation code

```
Enum = (enumeration)->
    check = (value)->
        newval = null
        for key, val of enumeration
            if val == value
                newval = value
                break
        if !newval
            throw "Invalid Enum Value: #{value}"

     result = (init)->
         state = init.call(enumeration)
         check state
         (callback)->
              value = callback.call(enumeration)
              if value == null or value == undefined
                  return state
              else
                  check value
                  state = value

      for key, value of enumeration
          result[key] = value 

      result
```

Obviously It would be much nicer if Coffeescript would have syntactic macros.
So we could write

```
Enum httpcodes
    ok: 200
    badrequest: 400
```

and

```
chrome = httpcodes 'ok
#or
chrome := 'ok
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is all just a mess. 1. It's not enum you're making here but an object with a switchable state and it has nothing to do with wikipedia quote of yours. 2. Both the object and the variables you assign it to are still unprotected from being assigned with values of any other type, because, once again, JavaScript is dynamic. 3. This whole facade will inevitably reduce performance. 4. The code speaks for itself about how complex and manageable it is. So, all those casualties for what exactly benefit? I'm sorry, but basically it's just an overcomplication with no practical purpose.

Comment: on 1) what is an enum other than an object with predefined switchable "states"? on 2) it would be very easy to extend this to create a property on any host via `Object.defineProperty`that you cant overwrite, on 3) yes it will be slower. But if you cant afford one or two indirections via function calls - you probably shouldnt use a javascript environment. on 4) I find 30 LOC pretty easy to manage. The complexity is a result of the "functional" approach and that approach again is the result of trying to be as dense as possible. But anyways - YMMY _ u dont like it? dont use it.

Comment: 1. Enum is a type which has a restricted set of possible values. It's not an object, its values are objects of it. 3. Treating performance as "not an issue" in any environment can only speak of the developer's qualification. And it's not about indirections only in your case, but unnecessary traversals. 4. Oh no you didn't just call a mutable state -based solution functional ) Please don't refer to things you obviously know nothing about just for the sake of the argument.

Answer (score 2):

```
Colors = Object.freeze({
  RED: 'red'
  GREEN: 'green'
  BLUE: 'blue'
})
console.log Colors.RED
# red
```

Values are constants (you can't change them):

```
Colors.RED = 'black'
console.log Colors.RED
# red
```

Answer (score 1):

I started the day wondering about `enums` in coffeescript and ended it with a solution [I published on github (available in npm, bower, meteor too)](https://github.com/sveinburne/enumerationjs#top). I tried to develop java-like enums, but even more flexible given the mix between prototype inheritance and classical inheritance coffeescript relies on.

Here is how it would fit your code :

```
class SomeService
  someFunc: -> SomeService.SomeEnumValue
  #A cool hack, but it must be the last class statement. 
  #Your class will now inherit this enumeration's properties. 
  #If you find this too hacky, you can always have a public static 
  #states class property instead.
  @__proto__:new Enumeration('SomeService',{
          SomeEnumValue :400
          SomeOtherValue:402
      })

ok = new SomeService()

alert ok.someFunc().id() #shows 400

if (ok.someFunc() is SomeService.SomeEnumValue) then alert ' some enum value'
```

But what's cool in this implementation, is that your enum can have specific fields, and inherit from a prototype (3d constructor argument) though uniqueness is guaranteed. That allows you to refactor your code and move some logic inside those function. Let's now ask this enum value to tell us something when he needs to, by defining a `tell` function.

```
class SomeService
  someFunc: -> SomeService.SomeEnumValue
  #A cool hack, but it must be the last class statement. 
  #Your class will now inherit this enumeration's properties. 
  #If you find this too hacky, you can always have a public static 
  #states class property instead.
  @__proto__:new Enumeration('SomeService',
                SomeEnumValue : { _id:400, text: ' some enum value' }
                SomeOtherValue: { _id:402, text: null } 
        , tell:->if @text? then alert @text)

ok = new SomeService()

alert ok.someFunc().id() #shows 400

ok.someFunc().tell()
```

Hope this helps someone, you can check the github address to have a look at the implementation and some more detailed documentation I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

For people looking for a simpler solution, that doesn't need to be fail-safe, where the values of the keys don't matter:

```
Priority = {
  "LOW"
  "HIGH"
}

priority = Priority.HIGH
```